# Getting Angular Twitter API app working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, twitter

I have been trying to get the following [angular twitter API app](https://github.com/twitterdev/sample-angular-node) to work out of the box but am running into an error on startup.

I am running node v0.10.36, npm 1.4.28

I just wanted to throw it out to the wider community to see if anyone could help me out.

I am trying to get the app working and am running into the error below. I tried a couple of things eg changing port, changing package.json to reflect a newer version of npm but I just don't seem to be able to get it to work. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

It looks like all the node modules installed correctly.

```
/Users/billyjlennon/sample-angular-node/routes/tweets.js:36
    var i = 0, len = tweets.length;
                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at /Users/billyjlennon/sample-angular-node/routes/tweets.js:36:28
    at responseHandler (/Users/billyjlennon/sample-angular-node/node_modules/twit/lib/oarequest.js:362:14)
    at passBackControl (/Users/billyjlennon/sample-angular-node/node_modules/twit/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:374:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/billyjlennon/sample-angular-node/node_modules/twit/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:386:9)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

It would be such a handy app if I could get it to work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you done this per the readme:

Create a config.js file using config.sample.js as a template. Fill in your Twitter App API Keys. You will need to create a Twitter application.

The fact that length is undefined indicates you aren't getting any data back.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I have done this. I just regenerated the keys to be sure. It is still not working. Is there any chance that you could try get it to run to see if you encounter problems?